# Android Listeners VS Monodroid EventHandlers

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android

Are the Monodroid / Xamarin.Android exclusive EventHandlers (ie, AdapterView.ItemClick) meant to be for convenience over the stock Android Listeners (AdapterView.setOnItemClickListener()) such that they can be interchanged arbitrarily with one another, or do they provide some sort of work around or something ?

In either case, *I'm having trouble figuring out what the object parameter is (ie, **sender**) in the EventHandler*, and cannot find documentation on it anywhere.

AndapterView.ItemClick's EventHandler is defined as:

```
public void ItemClickEventHandler(object sender, ListView.ItemClickEventArgs args)
{
   // what is sender ?
}
```

and the Android specific Listener looks like:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
{        
   // sender == parent ??
   // sender == view ??
}
```

Therefore, *I'd like to assume that **sender** is equivalent to **parent** or **view**.*

**Is there a convention for what sender is assigned to across all of the Monodroid exclusive EventHandlers ?**

I would also greatly appreciate some documentation for this, as I couldn't find it here: http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Widget.AdapterView and my trial for Reflector ran out (otherwise I'd look myself).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**sender** is the containing parent of the view that is clicked on (so, in this case, it would be an **AdapterView**).

The arguments from the associated Android Listener are packaged up in **args**

**THANKS SLaks !!!**

```
public class ItemClickEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private AdapterView parent;
    private View view;
    private int position;
    private long id;

    public AdapterView Parent { get { return this.parent; } }
    public View View { get { return this.view; } }
    public int Position { get { return this.position; } }
    public long Id { get { return this.id; } }

    public ItemClickEventArgs(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.view = view;
        this.position = position;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```